# Subtotal cart variable php WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, subtotal

Does anyone know what `$variable` to use in `php` to get the subtotal of the cart?
Subtotal = total value of cart BEFORE discount or taxes.

It would help me a lot.
I want to add an extra fee if the subtotal is above 250 euro.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can check here http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_cartget_cart_subtotal/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is multiple ways to get cart subtotal:

1. With `global $woocommerce;` variable *(the old way-*:

   global $woocommerce;
   $woocommerce->cart->subtotal;
   // or
   $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal()
2. Without `global $woocommerce;` variable using simply `WC()` *(nowadays)*:

   WC()->cart->subtotal
   // Or
   WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal()

References:

- [WooCommerce wc_cart class](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/class-reference/#wc_cart)
- [WooCommerce WC_Cart API Docs](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Any idea how I can get the shipping country?

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work..
I would like the Woocommerce shipping country to use in an if-rule in functions.php to add an extra fee. So 'if shipping country is BE (Belgium), the fee is €20'. It's just the 'if shipping country is BE' that i'm struggling with. I can't find the right code

Comment: is there anyway to change the subtotal of cart using this?

Answer (score 10):

I kept getting an incorrect subtotal (a little high, but could not determine why) using Loic's code snippets. 
 I tried every similar variant and eventually found the following code:

```
WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
```

Using this snippet above, I get precisely the amount expected which matches the actual subtotal displayed in the cart.

Now my 'free shipping' upsell calculation is working perfectly.

Comment: **NB** **get_cart_subtotal()** `If the cart has compound tax, we want to show the subtotal as cart + shipping + non-compound taxes (after discount).` https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_cartget_cart_subtotal/ **get_subtotal()** is just the goods subtotal before tax. I also had issues!